# Excel vba: call Worksheet_change from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have a workbook with two worksheets:

`Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

There is a `Worksheet_change` sub in `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ...
End Sub
```

There is a `Worksheet_Calculate` in `Sheet2`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    'Call Sheets("Sheet1").Worksheet_Change(Range("A1"))  'doesn't work
End Sub
```

How do I call the `Sheet1`'a `Worksheet_Change` subroutine from `Worksheet_Calcalculate` in `Sheet2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.Run` like that …

```
Application.Run "Sheet1.Worksheet_Change", Range("A1")
```

Note that `Sheet1` here is the VBA name of the sheet not the name on the tab. The VBA name can be changed in the property window of the sheet (in the VB Editor).

---

Alternatively move the code in your `Worksheet_Change` into a module like:

```
Public Sub MySpecificWorksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ...
End Sub
```

And call that from both `Worksheet_Change` and `Worksheet_Calculate`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MySpecificWorksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    MySpecificWorksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a `Can't run macro "Sheet1.Wokrsheet_change". Perhaps this macro is absent or all macros are turned off"` error (translation from my excel version)

Comment: Note that `Sheet1` is the VBA name of the sheet (added that info to the answer).

Comment: Thanks, I changed the VBA name of the sheet and now it works!

Answer (score 2):

Either:

- Change `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` to `Friend Sub Worksheet_Change`.
- Move the functionality of `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` into a friend/public sub and call it from both `Worksheet_Change` and `Worksheet_Calculate`. [Recommended]

Answer (score 0):

Calling the events in a worksheet is not different than calling any non-explicitly "Private" `Sub` or `Function` in any module or object. If they are not `Public` or `Friend`, they do not give their Functions, Subs and Properties being accessed without mentioning the place where they stay.

If the events are non-modified with the key word `Private` before them, they could be called with this code:

```
Sub TestMe
    Sheet1.Worksheet_Change Range("A1")
End Sub
```

If someone has explicitly added the word `Private` to start of the event, so it looks like this:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`, then we should really consider not accessing the event. If still, we want to access it, it can be done with `Application.Run`.

```
Application.Run "Sheet1.Worksheet_Change", Sheet1.Range("A1")
Application.Run CStr(Worksheets(1).CodeName & ".Worksheet_Change"), Range("A1")
```